# ggplot geom_bar stacked bar chart height (y)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the "Details" section of geom_bar documentation [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html), I see that in order to get show the data values one needs to use stat = "identity", but this renders the bars where the height of the stacked bar chart = a + b + c (each being components of the stack). I would like the bar chart to be max (a, b, c).  Any ideas how one can do this?

Comment: To get some helpful responses I suggest adding some sample data and code. Also, if the bar height equals max(a, b, c) what happens to the other 2 values in that bar?

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to process your data first. But noone can properly help you with out a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).